# evaluate expression in intellij protractor - doesn't perform any task on the browser. Promise related?

Tags: intellij-idea, protractor, evaluate

Consider running the following codes in Intellij:

```
it('Sales Force Test',  function(){
    browser.get(obj.URL_SF_UAT);
    browser.sleep(5000).then( function(){
            obj.username.sendKeys("arijit.chowdhury@xxxx")        
      *     obj.password.sendKeys("xxx");
```

Put a breakpoint on the last line. Run the script in debug mode.
Actual result: The driver open the browser and load the URL (line 2 of the codes) and stops. 
Expectation: Since the breakpoint is added in the last line, I would expect "obj.username.sendKeys("arijit.chowdhury@xxxx");" to get executed as well. But it doesn't get executed. Any reason?

Also, I tried the evaluate expression for "obj.username.sendKeys("arijit.chowdhury@xxxx");
But no action is performed on the browser. How to evaluate expression for protractor in Intellij?

Any help will be much appreciated.

regards, 
Arijit

Answer (score 1):

So this will explain why your breakpoint does not work (https://youtu.be/6aPfHrSl0Qk?t=1051). Basically Protractor queues up promises on the control flow and get executed after your `it` block completes.

### Debugger working with control flow turned off

How to fix it, use should use async / await by adding `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,` to your configuration file. You will then use async / await in your test and follow the steps in the ng-conf YouTube video. Basically you will need to use `node --inspect-brk ./node_modules/.bin/protractor conf.js` where conf is your Protractor configuration file.

```
it('Sales Force Test',  async () => {
    await browser.get(obj.URL_SF_UAT);
    await browser.sleep(5000);
    await obj.username.sendKeys("arijit.chowdhury@xxxx");
    debugger;   
  * await obj.password.sendKeys("xxx");
```

### The possible quick fix to your `it` block (without the debugger working)

Also you might notice that your previous test might not work as expected. To fix it not using async await. I would do:

```
it('Sales Force Test',  () => {
    browser.get(obj.URL_SF_UAT);
    // this thenable statement is not needed, jasminewd should await this
    // however the break points will not work.
    browser.sleep(5000).then(() => {
      return obj.username.sendKeys("arijit.chowdhury@xxxx").then(() => {
        return obj.password.sendKeys("xxx");
      });
    });
```